# Which is better? StorageFile class or IsolatedStorage class

Tags: windows-phone-8

Im developing a new WP8 app(using C#). In that i need to do file manipulation. Seems to be both of them have similar functions. so, Which is best and easy for simple file manipulation?

Comment: This is very opinion-based and this question will very likely be closed. Please provide a specific use case and a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with a lot of files, and you only want to use files in your own private folder, and you don't care about portability to Windows desktop, and performance is a concern, I would consider `IsolatedStorageFile` since it is significantly faster. But for most use cases the performance difference should not be a concern (if in doubt, write a quick sample app and see if it matters), and I would use `StorageFile` for future portability to Windows (plus ability to adapt to brokered files like photos etc. in the future).

Two other considerations are portability to non-Windows platforms and whether you need to deal with existing code that can't be made async-aware (both count as votes against `StorageFile`).

Answer (score 0):

Both APIs are used to manipulate file. StorageFile is available for both Windows Phone and WinRT, but IsolatedStorage type is available just for Windows Phone. I think you can go with IsolatedStorage.